# How can I receive a visa for a short trip to Ireland, as a resident of Germany?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, ireland, german-residents

I have been living in Germany for almost 3 years now and would like to visit Dublin in October. I am a student and have the resident permit for Germany. I have read a post that since my intention of travel is not a school excursion I might have to apply for a short term visiting visa for Ireland.

What are the procedures to apply for a travel visa? Is it possible to apply online or are there provisions to get an on arrival visa in Dublin? I have Ryanair flying to Dublin from my city and I would really like to go to Ireland.

Comment: You have to apply online but will also have to go (or send documents?) to the embassy: https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/germany/our-services/visas/visas-for-ireland/

Comment: Ireland doesn't do on-arrival visas. They want to actually pre-screen whom they let in, not just levy a tourism tax disguised as a visa fee.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it makes a difference but it *might* be helpful to know your nationality.

Comment: Hi @mts I am Indian. Of course I need to apply for a visa now thanks to Henning s shared link. It looks too complicated providing itinerary when I am the go with the flow guy.

Comment: How did you ever get residence in Germany, then? That's far more complicated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the procedures to apply for a travel visa?

You would need to apply for a regular tourist visa at the nearest Irish consulate. You can find a [detailed guide on how to apply for a visa](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist) at the Irish INIS website.

> Is it possible to apply online or are there provisions to get an on arrival visa in Dublin?

Citizens of [certain countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ireland) may visit Ireland visa-free, however there's no such thing as an "on arrival" visa for other nationals, including Indians with a German residence permit.

You may apply for a visa online (see my link above), however you would still need to visit the consulate to submit your documents and undergo an interview.

> I have Ryanair flying to Dublin from my city and I would really like
>   to go to Ireland.

While you may not visit Ireland visa-free, having a German residence permit is a great way of showing you are unlikely to overstay your visa and therefore your chances of getting a visa are very high.